# java des cipher different results on windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, security, encryption

I have an API documentation that requires encrypting a key to authenticate,
I managed to build and compile their sample code, but the results on windows are different than linux.

When I run and test from Windows, all seems to be correct and works with the API.

That same test on Linux outputs a different result. I need it working on Linux since that's the main server.

I am using & running the same jar file on both environments.

This is the key I am trying to encrypt (it's a dynamic key):

> 2136230$486B91E1BEA5D082BA3601CD803585CE$20140409$20140409$$ABCDEFGH$Reserved$CTC

This is the correct output on Windows (it's obviously quite longer):

```
F7BE2B7E0CEAD9D09135FCF2A8AEB11E2937D26B33CCBC9B8132A29A3534040C9737B2A8E3F271A9DF6454696CF890F7886223AE9C86F81EF58E41AEAA3D34A80F7089154E64F4FD36E75C25A7C2DA7FF03D21F57DA950F5
```

This is the wrong output from Linux:

```
F66D4CE1238B30EE54ABC74966D7AC3064FEA3ADFB9D37548E41509CE4FED9CB1D146651B491F2433169999A85F73DAF9ACD07A090DF3D85477BE4201ADC9E1A0181EA7CB763050A
```

What is causing this and how to correct it ?

This is the source code of the program to use as we received from the API company:

```
public class DESUtil
{
    private static final String Algorithm = "DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding";// DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding;DESede

    private static final String DESede = "DESede";

    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] keybyte, byte[] src)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, Exception
    {
        SecretKey deskey = new SecretKeySpec(keybyte, DESede);
        Cipher c1 = Cipher.getInstance(Algorithm);
        c1.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, deskey);
        return c1.doFinal(src);
    }

    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] keybyte, byte[] src)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, Exception
    {
        SecretKey deskey = new SecretKeySpec(keybyte, DESede);
        Cipher c1 = Cipher.getInstance(Algorithm);
        c1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, deskey);
        return c1.doFinal(src);
    }

    public static String byte2hex(byte[] b)
    {
        StringBuffer hs = new StringBuffer();
        String stmp = "";
        for (int n = 0; n <b.length; n++)
        {
            stmp = (java.lang.Integer.toHexString(b[n] & 0XFF));
            if (stmp.length() == 1)
                hs.append("0").append(stmp);
            else
                hs.append(stmp);
        }
        return hs.toString().toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
    }

    public static byte[] hex2byte(String hexStr)
    {
        if (hexStr.length() % 2 != 0)
        {
            AppLogger.error("hex2bytes's hexStr length is not even.");
            return null;
        }

        byte[] toBytes = new byte[hexStr.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i <hexStr.length(); j++, i = i + 2)
        {
            int tmpa = Integer.decode(
                "0X" + hexStr.charAt(i) + hexStr.charAt(i + 1)).intValue();
            toBytes[j] = (byte) (tmpa & 0XFF);
        }
        return toBytes;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Security.addProvider(new com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE());
        final byte[] rawKey = "db90e7eb".getBytes();
        final byte[] keyBytes = new byte[24];

        for (int i = 0; i <rawKey.length; i++)
        {
            keyBytes[i] = rawKey[i];
        }

        for (int i = rawKey.length; i <keyBytes.length; i++)
        {
            keyBytes[i] = (byte)0;
        }

        String szSrc = "20926330$AD75B1697FB5EB6345B2D412124030D2$10086$10086$10.164.111$ABCDEFGH$Reserved$CTC";
        System.out.println("string before encrypt:" + szSrc);
        byte[] encoded = null;

        try
        {
            encoded = encrypt(keyBytes, szSrc.getBytes());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("string after encrypt::" + byte2hex(encoded));

        byte[] srcBytes = null;

        try
        {
            srcBytes = decrypt(keyBytes, encoded);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("string before decode: :" + (new String(srcBytes)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess either a character set encoding problem or a salt problem.

Comment: Using the code with the `szSrc` value either from the code or from the question results in encrypted value different from both output values in the question. You should really provide exactly one input value that causes the problem and the output values corresponding to it instead of random unrelated data.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly your use of `szSrc.getBytes()` which uses the platform's default character encoding.

Try `szSrc.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")` as a starter if it's working on Windows, but if this string comes from an external service you should determine the encoding scheme dynamically (eg. if it comes through a Servlet use `httpRequest.getCharacterEncoding()`).